# How to scrape the href property of <a> tag in R/Python?

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am learning web scraping using `rvest`. The goal is to get the `href` property of
`<a href="#!Synapse:syn21656973">docker.synapse.org/syn21654780/normcorr</a>` from this [website](https://www.synapse.org/#!Synapse:syn21654780/docker/).

[image]

I tried to use a R package, `rvest`:

```
pg <- "https://www.synapse.org/#!Synapse:syn21654780/docker/"
pg %>% read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(".displayInline, a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
# I can only some get:
"https://synapse.prod.sagebase.org/Portal.html#!Home:0"
```

Expected Result:

```
"#!Synapse:syn21656973"
```

How to retrieve the href from `<a>` select? Please feel free to use `Python` if needed.

Comment: `<a href="https://synapse.prod.sagebase.org/Portal.html#!Home:0">AJAX\n\t\t\t\t\t\tapplication crawl link</a>` this is how it looks like. Its `href` is different from what you have

Comment: okay,  Thanks. Is it possible to get the expected result? Or is it hidden by scraping? I can see the value of href in inspect though.

Comment: even with inspect, i do not se the href you are talking about

Comment: Just added an image @onyambu

Comment: Is it because the data is dynamic?

Comment: Does a `RSelenium` solution fits you?

Comment: @nad-pat Whatever solution works, as long as it can solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the anchor text and then construct the url on your own.

First the the username from the subdomain and then id from upcoming part of the text of the anchor

docker.<username_here>.com/<id_here>/remainingtetxt.

just construct <username_here>/<id_here>

Comment: the syn Id in anchor text is different from url in a tag: syn21654780 vs syn21656973

Comment: Could you please provide an example if you have a solution? Thank you

Comment: As I mentioned, the ids are different between text and href. So I cannot make url using contents of text. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A `RSelenium` solution,

```
#start browser 
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
       browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
#navigate
url <- 'https://www.synapse.org/#!Synapse:syn21654780/docker/'
remDr$navigate(url)
#get the links
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.displayInline') %>% html_nodes('a') %>% 
  html_attr('href')
[1] "#!Synapse:syn21654780/wiki/"       "#!Synapse:syn21654780/files/"      "#!Synapse:syn21654780/datasets/"   "#!Synapse:syn21654780/tables/"    
[5] "#!Synapse:syn21654780/challenge/"  "#!Synapse:syn21654780/discussion/" "#!Synapse:syn21654780/docker/"     "#!Synapse:syn21656973"
```